Named/External Credentials and grant_type=account_credentials for Zoom API
I'm building a Salesforce > Zoom API integration. I have apex classes that handle oAuth and the API calls, but my client id/ secret are just hardcoded in there at the moment.
I obviously need to move these out. I thought about a custom metadata record etc. but the Named Credentials feature seemed like it was purpose built for handling this kind of thing.
Given this is Server > Server communication, Zoom's "grant_type=account_credentials" seemed appropriate for authenticating to the Zoom API and getting a Bearer token to use in subsequent requests. I have this working in Apex.
But I cant seem to add this grant_type, or other data into the body of the POST that is sent out to "https://zoom.us/oauth/token" in Named Credentials, External Credentials etc.
Am I limited to just doing this purely in Apex/custom metadata record to achieve this grant_type=account_credentials"?
If so, that's fine, but I wanted to do it with Named Credentials, for security, good practice etc. if possible...
Here is the Apex method I already have working:
public static String getAccessToken() {
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(TOKEN_ENDPOINT);
    req.setMethod('POST');
    
    String basicAuth = CLIENT_ID + ':' + CLIENT_SECRET;
    String authHeader = 'Basic ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(basicAuth));
    
    req.setHeader('Authorization', authHeader);
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    
    String body = 'grant_type=account_credentials' +
                  '&account_id=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(ACCOUNT_ID, 'UTF-8');
    req.setBody(body); // *** I can't add this information into a Named/External Credential? ***
    
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
    
    if (res.getStatusCode() == 200) {
        Map<String, Object> responseBody = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
        return (String) responseBody.get('access_token');
    } else {
        throw new CalloutException('Failed to obtain access token: ' + res.getStatusCode() + ' - ' + res.getBody());
    }
}

Ideally, I would like to be able to do this in a Http Request Invocable Action created from a Flow (i.e. not an Apex Invocable Action, an "External Service" that uses the Named Credential instead). As we have non-coders that make Flows and would find this kind of thing super useful.
Note that the Zoom API doesn't allow the grant_type=client_credentials.
Thanks!

Am I limited to just doing this purely in Apex/custom metadata record to achieve this grant_type=account_credentials -  this grant/interface is not an oAuth standard, blame Zoom for that. Apex - yes, custom metadata - no. You can vault the credentials in Named or External Cred, then merge them in your callout.

thanks - ill try implement this..
